# javascript that can access element declared in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache

- List item

  ```
   i want a javascript that can access the button elements inside   
    the
   dot.append() function. so that when i clicked the button i 
   get the value of that  button.
   below is a piece of code that have been working on this morning.
    i appreciate any support or hint from anyone.Thank you in 
   advance.
   further more i am also new in youtube data api.
  ```

  ```js
     



      function main_search(){
    $("form").on("submit",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //after that we prepare the request
     var myRequest = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
     part: 'snippet',
   q: encodeURIComponent($("#query").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
              maxResults :5,
              type : 'video'   
     });
      //  then we execute the request
       myRequest.execute(function(response){
         var results = response.result;
      $.each(results.items, function(index,item){


   $("#results").append('<li>'+item.id.videoId+" "+item.snippet.title+"

       "+item.snippet.channelTitle+" "+item.snippet.description+" 
   
       "+item.snippet.publishedAt+" "+'<img 
                                                                                   src="'+item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url+'">'+'<button 
      class="class_btns" value="'+item.id.videoId+'">'+'get video url
      '+'</buttons>'+'</li>'+"<br>");
      });
      
     });
    });
    }

  function loadAPI(){
   gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyC1CJHONRDvyfSS3xAOG9SfW_VCXMoLK5Y");
   gapi.client.load("youtube","v3", function(){
    //my youtube api is read
    main_search();
   });
      }
  ```

  ```html
    
   <form action="#">
   <input type="search" id="search_string"   placeholder="Your string 
   goes  
    here...."></input>

   <input type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search_btn" value="search">
   </input>
   </form>

   <ul id="result_box"></ul>
   
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1
  /jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script src="search.js"></script>
  ```

Comment: event.target points to the target.  You can look at the button HTML from there

Answer (score 0):

Just divide your statement into two lines so that you can access the element later:

```
var element = document.createElement('<li>'+item.id.videoId+" "+item.snippet.title+"

     "+item.snippet.channelTitle+" "+item.snippet.description+" 

     "+item.snippet.publishedAt+" "+'<img 
                                                                                 src="'+item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url+'">'+'<button 
    class="class_btns" value="'+item.id.videoId+'">'+'get video url
    '+'</buttons>'+'</li>'+"<br>");

$("#results").append(element);
```

Or if you want a jQuery object instead:

```
var element = $('<li>'+item.id.videoId+" "+item.snippet.title+"

     "+item.snippet.channelTitle+" "+item.snippet.description+" 

     "+item.snippet.publishedAt+" "+'<img 
                                                                                 src="'+item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url+'">'+'<button 
    class="class_btns" value="'+item.id.videoId+'">'+'get video url
    '+'</buttons>'+'</li>'+"<br>");
```

You can then access whatever you want from the `element` variable.

Alternatively you can just grab the button later using the class if you keep your current code:

```
var button = $('.class_btns');
```

Comment: var button = $('.class_btns');    I HAVE  tried to acces the var button using the following line , but still nothing happens.    $(document).ready(function(){
 var button = $('.class_btns');
    button.each(function(index, item){
  $(this).click(function(){
   var btnVal = $(this).val();
           console.log(btnVal);
  });
     
  });
});

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing with all that code dude. if you just want the value of the buttons you can do `$('.class_btns').val()`, or if you want it on click you do `$('.class_btns').click(function(){console.log($(this).val())});`